# When I am using require() in chalk module it indicates "not supported" and `import` gives cannot use "outside"

Tags: node.js

I attempted to import and use the "chalk" library as such:

```
import fetch from 'chalk';
// I am working with chalk module 
console.log(fetch.blue("hello"));
```

and received error message that cannot use import "outside".

My Node version is: .

What I'd like to do is: .

Here is my attempt using `require`:

```js
const chalk = require('chalk');
```

Comment: have you added `{type: 'module'}` to your package.json?

Comment: you will need to fill out more information about what you're attempting to do and what failed:

Also just so you know `fetch` is typically reserved for the fetch library not a good name for the default export from `chalk`.

Comment: I'm suspecting the version issue. Try this. npm  uninstall chalk, npm install chalk@4.1.0